# How can i call an interface in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, interface

I do not have a project in my work and they have asked me to give me a pass, but after passing the whole project, there is a part that has given me a code error at the moment. Clearly it's my first time in Kotlin and I have no idea, but I do have an idea. I tried to solve it and I have not succeeded. So I was asking for help. I get an error right at the beginning of the

> = SpeechService.Lintener {

Here the code

```
private val mSpeechServiceListener = SpeechService.Listener { text: String?, isFinal: Boolean ->
    if (isFinal) {
        mVoiceRecorder!!.dismiss()
    }

    if (mText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        runOnUiThread {
            if (isFinal) {

                if (mText!!.text.toString().equals("hola", ignoreCase = true) || b == true) {
                    if (b == true) {
                        mText!!.text = null
                        mTextMod!!.text = text

                        repro().onPostExecute(text)
                        random = 2
                    } else {
                        b = true
                        mText!!.text = null
                        val saludo = "Bienvenido, ¿que desea?"
                        mTextMod!!.text = saludo
                        repro().onPostExecute(saludo)
                    }
                }

            } else {
                mText!!.text = text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here the interface

```
interface Listener {

    fun onSpeechRecognized(text: String?, isFinal: Boolean)

}
```

Please, help me. the error is "Interface Listener does not have constructor"

Answer (score 2):

The `SpeechService.Listener { }` syntax for SAM interfaces is only possible when the interface is written i Java (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). Because the interface is written in Kotlin, you have to write it like this:

```
private val mSpeechServiceListener = object : SpeechService.Listener {

    override fun onSpeechRecognized(text: String?, isFinal: Boolean) {
        // Code here
    }

}
```

You don't really need the `SpeechService.Listener` interface in Kotlin though. You could just use a lambda function. This depends on whether the interface comes from a library or if you've written it yourself though.

```
private val mSpeechServiceListener: (String?, Boolean) -> Unit = { text, isFinal ->
    // Code here
}
```